# Executing python script from php function?

Tags: php, python, bash

I want to execute a python script,`test.py`, from a php function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

def test() :
   print("test success")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

I can successfully execute it using php command line:

```
php -r '$message = exec("python3 ~/../scripts/test.py"); print_r($message);'
```

I've added the following to my php code:

```
$message = exec("python3 ~/../scripts/test.py", $output, $return_val);
```

When I execute it, nothing is output (no errors in devtools). When I print the variables, `$output` and `$message` are empty and `$return_val` is 2 ([misuse of shell builtins according to Bash documentation](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html)).

I know `exec()` is allowed after adding the following into the same function:

```
if (exec('echo TEST') == 'TEST')
    {
      echo 'exec works!';
    }
```

What could be causing this error? How can I execute the python script with php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web server does not share your home directory, so `~` will point to the wrong place. Specify the full path of the file instead.

`python3` will exit with `2` when it can't find the file, along with a helpful message on stderr. The web server error logs will confirm this, as will adding `2>&1` to your command to capture stderr as stdout in your variable.

Comment: That was it! Ha, so obvious now. The exit code confused me a bit. Thanks!